# how to resolve this Duplicate callback outputs error in Dash ploty

Tags: python, bootstrap-4, plotly, plotly-dash

In the callback for output(s):
page-content.children
Output 0 (page-content.children) is already in use.
Any given output can only have one callback that sets it.
To resolve this situation, try combining these into
one callback function, distinguishing the trigger
by using `dash.callback_context` if necessary.

I am getting the above error when I run the Dash app can anyone help me out with this.

This my layout part

```
   html.Div([
        dbc.Row(
            [
                dbc.Col(dbc.NavbarBrand(dcc.Link(
                    html.Button(children='HOME',
                                style={
                                    'marginLeft': '100px',
                                    'marginRight': 'auto',
                                    'display': 'inline-block',
                                    'align': 'center', 'color': 'white'}, ),

                    href='/', refresh=True))),
                dbc.Col(dbc.NavbarBrand(dcc.Link(
                    html.Button(children='OVERVIEW',
                                style={'margin-left': '100px',
                                       'margin-right': 'auto', 'color': 'white', 'align': 'center'
                                       }),
                    href='/apps/overview', refresh=True))),
                dbc.Col(dbc.NavbarBrand(dcc.Link(
                    html.Button(children='GRAPH',
                                style={'marginLeft': '100px',
                                       'marginRight': 'auto', 'color': 'white', 'align': 'center'
                                       }),
                    href='/apps/graph_page', refresh=True))),
                dbc.Col(dbc.NavbarBrand(dcc.Link(
                    html.Button(children='CONSOLE',
                                style={'marginLeft': '100px',
                                       'marginRight': 'auto', 'color': 'white', 'align': 'center'
                                       }),
                    href='/log_stream', refresh=True))),
            ],
            style={
                'height': 'auto',
                'width': 'auto',
                'background-color': '#101820',
                'align-items': 'center',
                'diplay': 'flex',
            },
            align="center",
            no_gutters=True,
        ),
        dcc.Location(id='url', refresh=False),
        html.Div(id='page-content', children=[])
    ]),
    html.Div([
                dcc.Dropdown(
                    id='demo-dropdown',
                    options=[
                        {'label': 'Dummy', 'value': 0},
                        {'label': 'CAN', 'value': 1},
                    ],
                    placeholder="Select a Mode",
                    searchable=False
                ),
                html.Div(id='dd-output-container')
            ])
])
```

These are my callbacks

```
@app.callback(
    Output('dd-output-container', 'children'),
    Input('demo-dropdown', 'value'))
def update_output(value):
    return 'You have selected "{}"'.format(value)


@app.callback(Output(component_id='page-content', component_property='children'),
              (Input(component_id='url', component_property='pathname')))
def display_page(pathname):
    if pathname == '/apps/graph_page':
        return graph_page.layout
    elif pathname == '/apps/overview':
        return overview.layout
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you listed all callbacks? Could you be registering them multiple times?

Comment: Agreed with [emher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68394425/how-to-resolve-this-duplicate-callback-outputs-error-in-dash-ploty#comment120880602_68394425) you most likely have another callback that also has  `page-content.children` as an output. The error message explains the error and how you could fix it clearly.

Comment: Actually, I was importing a variable from this script to the other when I am not doing its working. I have no idea why it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having a duplicate callback in another script which I didn't notice at first.

1. Make sure you have unique ids for each component in the layout.
2. Eliminate duplicate callbacks in any of the scripts.